# Optionally returning something in Java

Tags: java

I haven't been programming for a while so I have been a bit rusty. I've been stumped on this problem for a few hours, and I'm wondering what are the options for optionally returning something in java (or jumping back to the calling method when a certain condition is met - basically the doBranch method processes statements using parseStatementList amongst other things. I have changed the parseStatementList in various ways over the past few hours, but it does not make sense to that which is probably why it didn't work.

CALLING CODE: [Basically END, BLAH, BOO] is in SKIP_START_SET. parseStatement however deals with these as normal words, and so if BOO is in a string or a list of some sort, it gets lost on the first doBranch.

```
    private C1 parseSelectStatement( TokenSet recoverSet) {

    C2 selectCond = doBranch( recoverSet );

    while (tokens.isMatch(BLAH)) {          
        match(BLAH)         
        C2 result = doBranch ( recoverSet );
    } 


    if (tokens.isMatch(BOO)) {
        match(boo)
        result1 = doBranch( recoverSet );
    }

    match( END )

    return new StatementNode.SelectNode(selectCond, result, result1);

}

private C2 doBranch(TokenSet recoverSet) {
    ExpNode cond = parseCondition(recoverSet.union(Token.KW_THEN));

    // The code jumps to below if words in SKIP_START_SET are found in the statement,
    // otherwise it will complete and return the new object.
    StatementNode result = parseStatementList(recoverSet.union(SKIP_START_SET));

    if (tokens.isIn(SKIP_START_SET)) {
        return null;
    }

    return new C2(pos, cond, result);       
}
```

Comment: I don't think `java.lang.Object` has a constructor that accepts parameters.

Comment: Well what's wrong with th ecode you've provided? It returns `null` or a result... is that not what you want? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: Seeing the use of a class named `Object` that isn't `java.lang.Obejct` fills me with dread about possible bugs that you may introduce from this confusion.

Comment: Can we see your error log?

Comment: To answer your question; in Java there is no "optional return". It is either "void" or a specific return type. Having said so, java 8 introduced https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: @Jägermeister: `result` is passed to his returned `Object`.

Comment: @Jägermeister : for pre-Java-8 it is possible to use Guava's Optional

Comment: @rkosegi Assuming that using external open source libraries is actually possible for him ;-)

Comment: I've just renamed the class to Object to make it generic - I don't want to return a null, because I run into problems with null pointer exceptions, I want to just break out of this function, and pass it back up to the method that called it, and not return anything - dealing with it in this method will produce an infinite coupling between the two methods.

Comment: Show us the calling code too. It's hard to see why you want this.

Comment: @weston - I've posted it up.

Comment: I see, when parsing, and one or another path is possible, it is common to peek the next token to decide.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8, you can use [Optional<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). In earlier versions you can achieve something similar, using third party libraries, like Guava.

Comment: I have neither option available to me :)

Answer (score 0):

At some point surely you want to check if the result is present? Can't you simply do a null check here? Alternatively, you could add a built-in check to your `ClassOfSomeSort`:

```
public class ClassOfSomeSort {
    public long pos;
    public String cond;
    public StatementNode result = null;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // Return true if no result is set...
        return result != null; 
    }

    public ClassOfSomeSort(long pos, String cond) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.cond = cond;
        this.result = null;
    }

    public ClassOfSomeSort(long pos, String cond, StatementNode result) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.cond = cond;
        this.result = result;
    }
}

private ClassOfSomeSort doBranch(TokenSet recoverSet) {
    ExpNode cond = parseCondition(recoverSet.union(Token.KW_THEN));

    // The code jumps to below if words in SKIP_START_SET are found in the statement,
    // otherwise it will complete and return the new object.
    StatementNode result = parseStatementList(recoverSet.union(SKIP_START_SET));

    if (tokens.isIn(SKIP_START_SET)) {
        return new ClassOfSomeSort(pos, cond);
    }

    return new ClassOfSomeSort(pos, cond, result);       
}
```

When you call the method, you can check for a result before you process it:

```
ClassOfSomeSort result = doBranch(...);
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    // Do something with result
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to reply, it's been a long night, but I'll have a fiddle early tomorrow morning with your suggestion and see how I go!

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the [**Optional<T> class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) stated in comments and in the other answer or if you want to avoid returning `null` you could return a list of your object which would be empty if you don't have any result to return :

```
private List<ClassOfSomeSort> doBranch(TokenSet recoverSet) {
    ExpNode cond = parseCondition(recoverSet.union(Token.KW_THEN));

    List<ClassOfSomeSort> myResult= new ArrayList<ClassOfSomeSort>();
    StatementNode result = parseStatementList(recoverSet.union(SKIP_START_SET));

    //if the condition is met you will have a result otherwise it will be an empty list
    if (!tokens.isIn(SKIP_START_SET)) { 
        myResult.add(new ClassOfSomeSort(pos, cond, result));
    }

    return myResult; //always return this list      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When parsing a language, and multiple paths are possible, it is common to *peek* the next token to decide. As oppose to following those paths anyway and handling if they fail.

Take this grammar:

```
<statement> ::= <digit> | <statement> <op> <statement> | '(' <statement> ')'
<digit>     ::= '0'..'9'
<op>        ::= '+' | '-' | '*' | '/'
```

Should be written like so:

```
Statement parseStatement(Queue<Token> tokens) {
   if (isDigit(tokens.peek()){ //look ahead
      return parseDigit(tokens);
   }

   if (tokens.peek()=='('){ //look ahead
      tokens.pop(); //eat '('
      Statement inner = parseStatement(tokens);
      match(tokens.pop(), ')'); //must have closing bracket
      return inner;
   }

   //otherwise must be one with a operator
   Statement lhs = parseStatement(tokens);
   Operator operator = parseOperator(tokens);
   Statement rhs = parseStatement(tokens);
   return new CompositeStatement(lhs, operator, rhs);
}
```